# Counting subrows in each row of a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matrix, count, grouping, matlab

I need an algorithm in Matlab which counts how many adjacent and non-overlapping `(1,1)` I have in each row of a matrix `A mx(n*2)` without using loops. E.g.

```
A=[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]  %m=2, n=5
```

Then I want

```
B=[2;3] %mx1
```

Comment: but in the second row they the `1111` are overlapping...

Comment: I mean: A=[(1 1) (1 0) (1 1) (0 0) (0 1); (1 0) (1 1) (1 1) (0 0) (1 1)]. Then, according to this separation, I have 2 (1 1) in the first row and 3 (1 1) in the second row

Comment: is that seperation to 2-elemnt long always the same? that is, for the case of `A=[ 0 1 1 0 ...]` you wont count them because `A=[(0 1) (1 0)...]` ?

Comment: That's right, 2 by 2 elements starting from the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specific case**

Assuming `A` to have ones and zeros only, this could be one way -

```
B = sum(reshape(sum(reshape(A',2,[]))==2,size(A,2)/2,[]))
```

**General case**

If you are looking for a general approach that must work for all integers and a case where you can specify the pattern of numbers, you may use this -

```
patt = [0 1] %%// pattern to be found out
B = sum(reshape(ismember(reshape(A',2,[])',patt,'rows'),[],2))
```

**Output**

With `patt = [1 1]`, `B = [2 3]`

With `patt = [0 1]`, `B = [1 0]`

Comment: ha ha ... and here I was trying to develop my code to explain ... nice one-liner though. You are right to precise that the input matrix should be `1` and `0` only, otherwise none of our solution (pretty similar) will work.

Comment: yes! With non-zero + non-ones thing, it would get messier! I am just too lazy to explain, OP must be benefited by the explanation you have there.

Comment: @LuisMendo haha mystic ways are the best ones !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `imresize` ,  for example

```
  imresize(A,[size(A,1),size(A,2)/2])>0.8

ans =
 1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1
```

this places `1` where you have `[1 1]` pairs... then you can just use `sum`

For any pair type `[x y]` you can :

```
x=0; y=1;
R(size(A,1),size(A,2)/2)=0; % prealocarting memory

 for n=1:size(A,1)
    b=[A(n,1:2:end)'  A(n,2:2:end)']
    try
       R(n,find(b(:,1)==x & b(:,2)==y))=1;
    end

end

R =
 0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: what do you mean "you think it doesn't work"  try the code and see that the answer is what you asked for...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It works perfectly, I like imresize. What if instead of (1,1) I want (0,1)?

Comment: then imresize wont benefit you since it wont be able to differentiate [0 1] from [1 0]. Let me think of a better way where you'll be able to tell any [x y] pair

Answer (score 1):

you can use transpose then reshape so each consecutive values will now be in a row, then compare the top and bottom row (boolean compare or compare the sum of each row to 2), then sum the result of the comparison and reshape the result to your liking.

in code, it would look like:

```
A=[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1] ;
m = size(A,1) ;
n = size(A,2)/2 ;

Atemp = reshape(A.' , 2 , [] , m ) ;
B = squeeze(sum(sum(Atemp)==2))
```

---

You could pack everything in one line of code if you want, but several lines is usually easier for comprehension. For clarity, the `Atemp` matrix looks like that:

```
Atemp(:,:,1) =
     1     1     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1
Atemp(:,:,2) =
     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1
```

You'll notice that each row of the original A matrix has been broken down in 2 rows element-wise. The second line will simply compare the sum of each row with 2, then sum the valid result of the comparisons.
*The squeeze command is only to remove the singleton dimensions not necessary anymore.*

Comment: +1 For the explanation! Our approaches look similar, except for the `squeeze` part!

Answer (score 0):

With `diff` (to detect start and end of each run of ones) and `accumarray` (to group runs of the same row; each run contributes half its length rounded down):

```
B = diff([zeros(1,size(A,1)); A.'; zeros(1,size(A,1))]); %'// columnwise is easier
[is js] = find(B==1); %// rows and columns of starts of runs of ones
[ie je] = find(B==-1); %// rows and columns of ends of runs of ones
result = accumarray(js, floor((ie-is)/2)); %// sum values for each row of A
```

Comment: In one of the comments here, OP mentions about `[0 1]` instead of `[1 1]`. So could this be modified for that case?

Comment: @Divakar I hand't seen that comment... No; my approach is based on detecting sequences of consecutive equal values. Modifying it to cover that case would probably mean changing it completely

Comment: Yeah that actually motivated me to present a generic solution. OP should have mentioned about that at the start, but still not clear if OP really wants it, so hold onto this.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I disapprove of comments or question edits that change the question completely, specially after an answer has been given focusing on the original case